# How can I use devtools in a chrome extension with manifest v3?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Basically, I have a chrome extension that I want to be able to use the chrome devtools api. However, when I try to load the extension with devtools specified in the manifest's permissions, I get this error:

> Permission 'devtools' cannot be specified in the manifest. Could not load manifest.

I've also tried moving it into optional_permissions, but that still produces the same result.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, i'm new to this.

Comment: There's no such permission. You can [declare a devtools page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) or use devtools protocol via chrome.debugger API.

Comment: Post your manifest.json so we can see what you're working with.

Comment: I did a little more reading in the documentation, and I don't think what I was trying to do is possible. Basically, I was trying to have the extension get some data from requests that the website makes. However, i'm pretty sure you need to actively have the devtool panel open, which isn't what i'm looking for.

Comment: maybe you're looking for [chrome.webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/) (`webRequest` permission)